# Only One Sticky Radio Button in PHP Form

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

I'm working on a quiz form made with PHP that requires the radio buttons to be sticky when the user presses the submit button so that the answers are still checked. (There are five questions with three radios each.) When testing the page, only the first set of radio buttons remains checked. The last four revert back to unchecked. How can I fix this?

This is my code to create the quiz form.

```
foreach($quiz['choices'][$key] as $choice){

    echo "<label>";

    if(isset($_POST['submit']) and $_POST['submit'] == $key){
        echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"$key\" value=\"$choice\" id=\"$choice\" checked> " . $choice . "<br>";
    }else{
        echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"$key\" value=\"$choice\" id=\"$choice\"> " . $choice . "<br>";
    }

    echo "</label>";
```

Comment: The name of these radio buttons is not `submit` but whatever is in `$key`...the name should be static and you should be checking values I think...

Comment: When you say that you want the radio buttons to be sticky, what do you mean?

Comment: Aside: projects can get rather difficult to maintain if you trap your HTML tags in `echo` statements. When you get a moment, look at doing the dynamic output in small PHP tags, and all static stuff can then just be HTML ([see example](https://github.com/halfer/php-tutorial-project/blob/master/edit-post.php)). You'll find syntax colouration and tag matching in your IDE will work better, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close! Check if the key has been posted.

```
foreach($quiz['choices'][$key] as $choice){
    echo "<label>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='$key' value='$choice' id='$choice'";
    if(isset($_POST[$key]){ echo 'checked'; }
    echo "> " . $choice . "<br>";
    echo "</label>";
}
```